# Can't get junit to work with Struts2 convention plugin, annotations, Tiles, Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, struts2, annotations

I am using the Struts2 convention plugin along with tiles and annotations and am using Maven for building the project. I am having problems getting junit to successfully run. The root error message seems to be

```
Caused by: The Result type [tiles] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class com.mycompany.myproject.web.actions.security.ResendConfirmationAction] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [com.dr_dee_sw.campaigner.web.actions.security#convention-default#/security] - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultConfig(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:450)
```

I'm getting this error for all my Struts2 actions, not just the one listed.

The ResendConfirmationAction is below

```
@Results({ @Result(name = "success", type = "tiles", location = "resend-confirmation"),
      @Result(name = "input", type = "tiles", location = "resend-confirmation") })
public class ResendConfirmationAction extends ActionSupport
{
  ...
}
```

My struts.xml file is below:

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="campaigner_messages" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?/campaigner.*?jar(!/)?,.*?/dr-dee-commons-1.0.*?jar(!/)?"/>
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="file,jar,zip"/>
  <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="convention-tiles5"/>
  <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/"/>  
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="convention-tiles5" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
  </package>
</struts>
```

I'm sort of assuming that junit can't find my struts.xml file. I've put it in the following locations with no success

- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
- src/main/resources/WEB-INF/classes
- src/test/resources/WEB-INF/classes
- src/test/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

An example of a junit test is below:

```
public class ResendConfirmationActionTestCase extends AbstractStrutsSpringTestCase
{
  @Test
  public void testSuccess() throws Exception
  {
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/security/resend-confirmation");
    ResendConfirmationAction action = (ResendConfirmationAction)proxy.getAction();

    // Setup
    request.setParameter("accountReason", "Bruce");
    request.setParameter("clearTextPassword", "test");
    request.setParameter("email", "test");
    request.setParameter("firstName", "test");
    request.setParameter("lastName", "test");
    proxy.setExecuteResult(false);

    // Execute
    String result = proxy.execute();

    // Test Results
    assertTrue(action.getFieldErrors().size() == 0);
    assertEquals(Action.SUCCESS, result);
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you use junit?

Comment: Does it work if you're running it on server?

Comment: I'm using junit as part of the Maven build process. So, for this example, I'm trying to run ResendConfirmationActionTestCase. I'll add that to the description.

Comment: Yes, the actual code works when running on Wildfly 8.

Comment: `WEB-INF` in `resources` looks strange. :) Try just `src/main/resources` or `test`.